# Is there a way to have text inline in an SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've got an SVG of an iPhone, on it I've added some JS to change the clocks time and date to the current date/time relative to the user.

The image is an SVG and inside I'm defining the text elements with a `<text>` tag but it seems that I can only y-align or x-align each tag. The issue with this is as the numbers change, some of the numbers have different widths which then pushes it either closer or further away from its sibling.

Basically, I'm wanting to achieve something which can be done with flex. For example, if `.flex` has flexbox assigned to it:

```
<div class="flex">
    <div>13</div>
    <div>:</div>
    <div>23</div>
</div>
```

This would pull all the divs inline and the widths of the divs would expand where necessary keeping everything inline, neat and tidy. [Like this](https://codepen.io/mrmathewc/pen/qexgJR).

I'm wanting the widths of the elements inside the SVG to change, but stay centered in the image without offsetting to the left or right a little but. The same applies for the date also.

Please see this example: https://codepen.io/mrmathewc/pen/vodbmm

The screen the time and date are contained in is 300px in width.

Search the id `hours`, `minutes`, `date` within the SVG to see where the `<text>` element is positioned.

I've seen someone mention putting `<rect>` elements above the text items, which I've tried but not had any luck achieving what I want.

I've also tried adding the time into one `<text>` element, rather than splitting it up but again, as the numbers change my issue persists.

If anyone could shine some light on this, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to translate the group. You can add a x and y attributes to the text and use `text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"` to center the text around the {x,y} point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use `text-anchor` so that you can align hours to the right and the full date to the middle. It will adapt to the text size:

```
<g id="Group" opacity="0.8" transform="translate(285.777635, 160.997429)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
  <text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="0" fill="white" class="clock-numerals" id="hours">00</text>
  <text x="60" y="0" fill="white" class="clock-numerals">:</text>
  <text x="75" y="0" fill="white" class="clock-numerals" id="minutes">00</text>
</g>

<g id="Group" opacity="0.8" transform="translate(294.228792, 190.920308)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="60" fill="white" class="clock-date" id="date">1</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<tspan` and you can give it x and y like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500">
  <text x="10" y="30" class="small">
    You are
    <tspan x="10" y="40">not</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="50">a banana!</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

which gives you this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG8zk.png)

notice that `tspan` and `text` have the same x and `tspan` y increases so it will appear lower.

You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan